# d3 stacked bar only updates 3 times

Tags: d3.js, stack, transition

I want a horizontal stacked bar to update more than 3 times. I am not using random data but actual data. I have data for 60 years. This example has four, but it will only update 3 years.

It uses data.filter, but when I try to use ++years it will not update the bars. It will only say stack.exit is not a function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
  body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)

    var data = [
      { year: 2005, bananas: [10, 20, 30, 20], apples: [20, 10, 30, 10], pears: [30, 10, 20, 50] },
      { year: 2006, bananas: [30, 40, 20, 30], apples: [30, 30, 40, 20], pears: [40, 20, 30, 50] },
      { year: 2007, bananas: [50, 50, 30, 40], apples: [40, 40, 50, 30], pears: [50, 30, 40, 50] },
      { year: 2008, bananas: [70, 60, 30, 50], apples: [50, 50, 60, 40], pears: [60, 40, 50, 50] }
 ];

    const BAR_HEIGHT = 50
    const FRUITS = ['bananas', 'apples', 'pears']
    const COLORS = ['#21CD69', '#f8bc29', '#fb4848', '#ccc']

    svg.selectAll('g.stack')
        .data(FRUITS)
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'stack')
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(0, ${i * (BAR_HEIGHT + 10)})`)

    function update (year) {
      var filteredData = data.filter(i => i.year === year)[0]

            svg.selectAll('g.stack').nodes()
        .forEach((node, i) => {
            const fruitName = FRUITS[i]
            const t = d3.transition().duration(1000)
        const stack = d3.select(node)
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(filteredData[fruitName], d => d)
            stack.exit()
            .transition(t)
            .attr('width', 0)
            .remove()

          let x = 0
          stack.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('y', 0)
            .attr('height', BAR_HEIGHT)
            .merge(stack)
            .attr('fill', (d, i) => COLORS[i])
            .transition(t)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                const retX = x
              x += d * 5
              return retX
            })
            .attr('width', d => d * 5)
        })
    }

    let year = 2005
    let inc = 0
    update(year)

    setInterval(() => {
      inc = (inc + 1) % 3
      update(year + inc)
    }, 2000)

 </script>
</body>
```

A stacked bar that updates up to 60 times with different data

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, as I get no errors after pasting it into a fiddle. It iterates over 3 years because of the `% 3` bit

Comment: That was it! Thank you!